# how to make embed with for loop inline false true discord bot python

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py, bots

i want to make the field one inline=True and next one False

```
for clans in results:
        embed.add_field(name=f"Name: {clans[0]}", value=f"lvl = {clans[1]} | xp = {clans[2]}. | date = {clans[3]} | leader = {clans[4]} | id = {clans[5]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
for value, clans in enumerate(results):

   if value%2 == 0:

        embed.add_field(name=f"Name: {clans[0]}", value=f"lvl = {clans[1]} | xp = {clans[2]}. | date = {clans[3]} | leader = {clans[4]} | id = {clans[5]}", description = '', inline = True)
   
   else:

        embed.add_field(name=f"Name: {clans[0]}", value=f"lvl = {clans[1]} | xp = {clans[2]}. | date = {clans[3]} | leader = {clans[4]} | id = {clans[5]}", description = '', inline =False)
```

Is this what you want ? :)